# Alternate term for customised version of a document

Tags: information-architecture, localization, content-strategy, version-control

We are currently using the word "Localisation" (sometimes "Localization") to mean a child version of a document (or folder) that has been then customised to fit a specific situation. In this case changes to the parent document triggers a notification for the child document(s).
Eg a set of procedures that is mostly the same but slightly different between departments in a company.

Using the word "localisation" has its problems as in the CMS world that pretty clearly means making a translated or otherwise *geographically* appropriate version of a document, so we'd like to change what we call it.

What would you call such a feature?

- We already call translations translations
- The term/idea "Reusable content" is already used...

Comment: I'd personally use the word "variant" or "alternative".

Comment: You might also want to try your question over at http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've had a bit of a look at synonyms and there's some good ideas there but what I'm really after is if there's an agreed or conventional word used in the CM or Knowledge Management domains.

Answer (score 1):

[Derivative](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/derivative)/[derivation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/derivation)/[derived](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/derived) comes to mind.

> Of, or pertaining to, conditions unique to the descendant species of a clade, and not found in earlier ancestral species.

also:

> Modern systematics proscribes use of derived to mean "advanced", preferring to use derived to simply mean "changed from the ancestral state" without an evaluation of quality.

You could also try to ask this question on [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Typically a **document** refers to a specific file.

If the document is cloned and then edited, that new document is often called a **version**.  For example, a financial report in Europe might be distributed in English, but may also have German and French versions.

If the master document is just a general form and it must be customized to be used, then the master is often considered a **template** and the specific customizations are **documents**.

Comment: Good point. We could look at the idea of flipping it and talking differently about the parent document rather than the child. We are already using the word/concept "template" though so can't use that.